# Download kaggle dataset using R

Tags: r, macos, terminal, download, pip

I would like to see if it is possible to download a set of datasets from a Kaggle competition using R.

Using this code:

```
system("pip install kaggle")
system("kaggle competitions download -c two-sigma-financial-news")
```

outputs a "sh: kaggle: command not found" even when I try to pip install kaggle it doesn't work, even though it does work in the mac terminal. Any advice from someone who was able to download and load datasets from Kaggle in R in the past?

Comment: The "terminal" of what?

Comment: mac terminal my bad!

Comment: You might try surrounding all or parts of that shell command with `shQuote` or you might try using fully specified paths, since you might be assuming different directories.  Or it could be a matter of different environment variables when using Terminal.app than when using R. You set environment variables for bash in a `.profile` file and environment variables in one of several possible locations describing in `?Startup`.

Comment: What **python** as a tag in this question?

Comment: Perhaps my fault. I thought pip was a python command. Am I wrong? https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pip-python-package-manager

Comment: I guess you can add a **pip** tag.

Comment: perhaps use the R package that interfaces to the Kaggle API? https://github.com/mkearney/kaggler

Comment: @42, yeah I thought it would work if Kaggle wasn't installed on my machine, which it is since it works fine in the terminal.